# Getting only the list of checkboxes from a collection of checkboxes for which status is changed(checked or unchecked) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with multiple rows and each row has a checkbox which is in either checked or unchecked state. The user can check or uncheck few of the checkboxes and hit the submit button to save their changes.

Is their any way to get only the list of checkboxes whose original state changed(from checked to unchecked or unchecked to checked)?

If this is possible then I will be able to provide the users with a single button to update or else I may have to give a button for each row to update.

I am also thinking of updating via ajax as soon as the status changes for each checkbox, but I prefer to make one server call by updating all at once.

Any information regarding this issue is very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You essentially have to know the original state of each checkbox, and whenever a checkbox's change event is triggered, update an array that holds a list of all the IDs of those elements (ie when the new value is different, the ID should be added to the array; when they're the same, remove it from the array).

Comment: There really isn't an issue in "resaving" all the checkboxes. I think it might be more efficient than trying to determine which ones have changed.  1 ajax call is less intensive than 20!

Comment: could you update all checkboxes' checked status via jquery, just taking the state they are in currently when the submit button is pressed?

Comment: oops sorry for the repeat @romo!  Looks like you are a quicker typer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `checked` attribute is set in the markup you can do this by using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

**js**

```
var changedInputs = $("input").filter(function() {
    var input = $(this),
        checked = (input.attr("checked") || "") === "checked";

    return (checked !== input.prop("checked"));
});

console.log(changedInputs);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QVTn5/1/)

Comment: It's way safer and quicker to just do var checked = input.is(':checked');

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble, @Derek: [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (have a look at the demo) gives the value of the attribute as set in the markup. `.is(:checked)` the current value as `.prop()`. The comparison here is specifically for markup to current value not current value to current value. And why should `.attr()` be deprecated?

Comment: Withdrew my comment as I see what you were getting at now.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas . This is what I was hoping for.